# matching pairs of points from a list for homography

Tags: python, opencv, matcher, vision, homography

I have two sets of points, let's say:

```py
Xim = [760, 545, 610, 462, 1054, 627, 735]
Yim = [-631, -54, -485, -319, -317, -170, -685]

Xreal = [0.75, 0.875, 0.125, -0.625, 2.375, -0.125, 0.25]
Yreal = [1.625, 1.875, 2.625, 3.5, 3.5, 4.25, 4.75]
```

They obviously describe the same pattern, just not in the same order (please bear in mind that it's never as "clean": my two lists are much longer, they don't have the same number of points, and there are outliers that just don't match anything; but that's another problem).

[https://imgur.com/x4YFH4k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBoXt.jpg)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBoXt.jpg
(Sorry, I can't post images yet, it's only my second post on the forum...)

I want to find the homography matrix that would help me predict the position of my second list from the second one.

```
pts_im = np.array([[Xim[x],Yim[x]] for x in range(len(Xim))])
pts_real = np.array([[Xreal[x],Yreal[x]] for x in range(len(Xreal))])
H, _ = cv2.findHomography(pts_real, pts_im, cv2.RANSAC)
```

This doesn't work, because my points are not matched together.

Is there a ready-to-use function that would help me match the points together? Or an approach that you could lead me on?

Thank you!